# Complex PHP for json_encode > how to handle/output right?

Tags: php, javascript, json

I have PHP which i need as a variable to work within my JavaScript. But my output is "destroyed". I think i don't handle right the json_encode, because the php is commented out with html .

```
$jsString = file_get_contents(get_stylesheet_directory() . '/formparts/search-model-vehicle-dropdowns-var.php');
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#model1").change(function () {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var jsStringFromPhp = <?php echo json_encode($jsString); ?>;
    if (val == "0") {
        $("#model2box").html("<option></option>");
    } else if (val == "bmw") {
        $("#model2box").html(jsStringFromPhp);
    } else if (val == "honda") {
        $("#model2box").html("<option value='test'>item3: test 1</option><option value='test2'>item3: test 2</option>");
    } else if (val == "ford") {
        $("#model2box").html("<option value='0'>Any</option><option value='mondeo'>Mondeo</option>");
    }
});
});
</script>
```

My /formparts/search-model-vehicle-dropdowns-var.php:

```
<?php if( $terms = get_categories( 'depth=2&taxonomy=model&parent=221') ) ) :
foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
    echo '<label class="w100"><input type="checkbox" name="model_' . $term->slug . '"/> ' . $term->name . '</label>';
endforeach;
endif;
; ?>
```

But with this i just get (in my outputes code):

```
<div id="model2box"><!--?php if( $terms = get_categories( 'depth=2&taxonomy=model&parent=221') ) ) :
foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
    echo '<label class="w100"--><input type="checkbox" name="model_' . $term->slug . '"> ' . $term-&gt;name . '';
endforeach;
endif;
; ?&gt;</div>
```

Or the actual result as a screenshot:

[image]

Any ideas how to solve/correct the output?

Comment: file_get_contents doesn't execute php. You also can't load a file directly and use the WordPress API, WordPress is not loaded in that context.

Comment: Hey @milo, thank you. Ok, "file_get_contents doesn't execute php" i understand. Maby i can use include...? But more important: "WordPress is not loaded in that context" > can you give me a hint to bring me to the right direction, how to do this? **Or** i know i should be possible to bring this PHP from external file direct into the script. But at the end, it dosn`t work at all. Equal how i tried. How you would solve this thing?

Comment: @wellseo yes use include then update your question